# Ajax working occasionally

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email

This ajax code is only working sometimes. Please solve my problem:

```
App.controller('sendemail', function (page) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://sanjuwebworks.com/content/9-mobileapps/sendemail.php?callback=response',
        // data to be added to query string:
        data: { name: 'Zepto.js' },
        // type of data we are expecting in return:
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 300,
        context: $('body'),
        success: function(data){
        // Supposing this JSON payload was received:
        //   {"project": {"id": 42, "html": "<div>..." }}
        // append the HTML to context object.
        alert(data.success)
        console.log('success',data)
},
error: function(xhr, type){
alert('Ajax error!')
} 
})
```

Only sometimes it's alerting and logging to the console,mostly it does not respond.

Comment: Remove `timeout:300` and try again.

Comment: yeah, 300ms timeout is unrealistic

Comment: thanks guys, it worked after removing the timeout

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax-call is working. If you call the URL directly from browser you will receive this:

```
{success: false}
```

Because you are using 'GET' you can add `&name=Zepto.js` to the URL, but the answer will be the same.

```
http://sanjuwebworks.com/content/9-mobileapps/sendemail.php?callback=response
```

So I would say that your PHP-function is not working correctly.

**EDIT:** But I extracted the AJAX-call out of your angular-function and called it via jQuery.